# R: How do you algebraically undo a weighted mean?

Tags: r, math, statistics

Let's say I have the following values:

```
ue <- c(0.1784545, 0.2248318, 0.2561000, 0.2722773, 0.2629545, 0.2797364 0.2294227)
ff <- c(679, 631, 588, 514, 380, 192 , 60)
r <-  c(0.6167, 0.8099, 0.9902, 1.0767, 1.1359, 1.2550, 1.6187)
```

I want to solve the following algebraic equation:

```
weighted.mean((1-(ue+x)*r), ff) = .58498
```

Where I want to solve for `x`. In other words, how much would I need to increase ue by in order to have the weighted mean of 1 minus product of `ue*r` and `ff` equal to .58498.

I can approximate this answer with a for loop, but I couldn't figure out how to do this algebraically.

Comment: If you want an algebraic solution this this is really a math problem. Probably a better fit for [math.se] or [stats.se].

Comment: I was considering posting there, but I'm answering the question in R, and it felt more convenient to use that notation rather than converting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
> ue <- c(0.1784545, 0.2248318, 0.2561000, 0.2722773, 0.2629545, 0.2797364, 0.2294227)
> ff <- c(679, 631, 588, 514, 380, 192 , 60)
> r <-  c(0.6167, 0.8099, 0.9902, 1.0767, 1.1359, 1.2550, 1.6187)
> f <- function(x)  (weighted.mean((1-(ue+x)*r), ff) - .58498)
> uniroot(f, lower=-100000000, upper=100000000)$root
[1] 0.2012965
```

Just make sure that you specify `lower` and `upper` in an appropriate way (based on your knowledge of the problem) to guarantee that the root is inside the interval.

If you don't it will throw you an error:

```
> uniroot(f, lower=50, upper=100000000)$root
Error in uniroot(f, lower = 50, upper = 1e+08) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just write the equation and do the math, it's not hard to find the following expression for `x`:

```
((1-.58498) * sum(ff) - sum(ff*r*ue)) / sum(ff*r)
# [1] 0.2012965
```

Below are the main steps of the calculation, written using `R` style. (They are not lines of code to execute, but just a quick explanation.)

```
weighted.mean((1-(ue+x)*r), ff) == .58498

sum(ff * (1 - (ue+x)*r)) == .58498 * sum(ff)

sum(ff) - sum(ff*(ue+x)*r) == .58498 * sum(ff)

sum(ff*(ue+x)*r) == (1-.58498) * sum(ff)

sum(ff*ue*r) + x*sum(ff*r) == (1-.58498) * sum(ff)
```

Hence the result: `x == ((1-.58498) * sum(ff) - sum(ff*r*ue)) / sum(ff*r)`